# "where" versus "find" in FreeBSD

Tags: find, freebsd, command

So I know that `where` command is a shell built in and as a result it performs faster and just finds executable files; but is there any other difference between the `where` and `find` commands?

Comment: I suppose you mean `whereis`

Comment: nope 'where' and 'whereis' are two different things

Comment: Other difference? So the fact that former is just a shell builtin and the latter is a full-fledged program with plenty of functionality is not enough? Read `find` manpage to find out all its features.

Comment: I don't seem to find a difference between `where` or `whereis` other then one of them is a builtin

Comment: Then you should ask a question, ADDB, because there most definitely is one.  But question comments on a rather different question are not the place for this.  There is a shell built-in named `where` in the TENEX C and Z shells and that is what the questioner is specifically asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're very different beasts. `where foo` in `tcsh` (also in `zsh`) just tells you where `foo` is located in your `$path` (or more exactly the different `foo` commands the shells knows about by looking in the list of shell builtins and keywords, aliases and executable files found via a lookup of `$PATH` (mapped to the `$path` array)). `find` is a fairly powerful command for searching for files according to various criteria.

For instance,

```
find /usr/local -type f -mtime -30 -atime +7 \( -user bob -o -user karen \) -perm -001 -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

will find any files in `/usr/local` that are ordinary files (not directories or anything), have been modified in the last 30 days but not accessed in the past week, belong to either `bob` or `karen`, and are executable by other. It then `chmod`s those files.

Comment: `locate` may also be of interest, even though not mentioned in the Q

Answer (score 1):

Just a sidenote: there's also the locate(1) command, which is somewhat similar to find(1) - in that it looks up for any kind of files, not just the ones in your $PATH (in other words: not just for "executable commands") - but uses a periodically rebuilt index, so it's pretty fast.